# Validating XML File with XSD gives different errors

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I'm trying the whole time to validate XML file with XSD and tried different options adding elements, sequences, complex type and nothing solves the problem.

Can please someone tell me, what exactly the problem is ? Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<literature
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:NoNameSpaceSchemaLocation="exerciseLiteraturSchema.xsd">

    <!-- First reference -->
    <reference number="1">
        <author>
            <firstname>Ron</firstname>
            <name>Jefferson</name>
        </author>
        <title>XML for Beginners</title>
        <editor>McGraw Hill</editor>
        <!-- <isbn>12-3344-567-00</isbn> -->
    </reference>

</literature>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsd:element name="literature">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="reference">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="author">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence>
                                    <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <xsd:element name="editor" type="xsd:string" />
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="number" type="xsd:integer" />
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the `xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="exerciseLiteraturSchema.xsd"` you can get a satisfying result using the following XSD:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<literature
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!-- First reference -->
    <reference number="1">
        <author>
            <firstname>Ron</firstname>
            <name>Jefferson</name>
        </author>
        <title>XML for Beginners</title>
        <editor>McGraw Hill</editor>
        <!-- <isbn>12-3344-567-00</isbn> -->
    </reference>

</literature>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xs:element name="literature">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="reference">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="author">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="editor" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:integer" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This XSD validates the above XML.
I moved the `title`and the `editor` elements out of the `author` element and added the `firstname` and the `name` elements instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how does the XML File know which Schema to use if it's not specified at the beginning ?

Comment: The XSD is usually a parameter to the validator. If not, it should be working with the `xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="exerciseLiteraturSchema.xsd"` attribute. So add it to the file and then check it with your validator.